# VueJS Doesn't interpret anymore my variables

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I just migrated from Laravel Elixir / Gulp to Laravel Mix.

Then, I was not able to keep VueJS 1, I had dependencies issues, so I migrated to VueJS 2

When I run `npm run dev` I get a Build OK.

When I check in Chrome, I can see that Vue is detected by browser, so it seems well installed.

I also ran `vue-migration-helper` and it detect no error.

Now, My issue is that my vue code in my HTML is no longer executed:

```
<select v-model="genderSelect" class="form-control">
            <option v-for="gender in genders" v-bind:value="gender.value">
                @{{ gender.text }}
            </option>
</select>
```

```

Generates :

```
<select v-model="genderSelect" class="form-control">
            <option v-for="gender in genders" v-bind:value="gender.value">
                {{ gender.text }}
            </option>
        </select>
```

so @ is not interpretting. I had it working before, here is my original file:

```
new Vue({
                el: 'body',
                data: {
                    isTeam: 0,
                    alias: '',
                    genderSelect: 'M',
                    ageCategorySelect: 0,
                    ageMin: 0,
                    ageMax: 0,
                    gradeSelect: 0,
                    gradeMin: 0,
                    gradeMax: 0,
                    error: '',
                    grades: [
                        {value: 0, text: no_grade},
                        {value: 2, text: '7 Kyu'},
                        {value: 3, text: '6 Kyu'},
                        {value: 4, text: '5 Kyu'},
                        {value: 5, text: '4 Kyu'},
                        {value: 6, text: '3 Kyu'},
                        {value: 7, text: '2 Kyu'},
                        {value: 8, text: '1 Kyu'},
                        {value: 9, text: '1 Dan'},
                        {value: 10, text: '2 Dan'},
                        {value: 11, text: '3 Dan'},
                        {value: 12, text: '4 Dan'},
                        {value: 13, text: '5 Dan'},
                        {value: 14, text: '6 Dan'},
                        {value: 15, text: '7 Dan'},
                        {value: 16, text: '8 Dan'}
                    ],
                    ageCategories: [
                        {value: 0, text: no_age},
                        {value: 1, text: childs},
                        {value: 2, text: students},
                        {value: 3, text: adults},
                        {value: 4, text: masters},
                        {value: 5, text: custom}
                    ],

                    genders: [
                        {value: 'M', text: male},
                        {value: 'F', text: female},
                        {value: 'X', text: mixt}
                    ],
                    categoryFullName: 'Individual Men',
                    url: '/api/v1/category/create',


                },
                computed: {
                    categoryFullName: function categoryFullName() {
                        var teamText = this.isTeam == 1 ? team : single;
                        var ageCategoryText = '';
                        var gradeText = '';

                        if (this.ageCategorySelect != 0) {
                            if (this.ageCategorySelect == 5) {
                                ageCategoryText = ' - ' + age + ' : ';
                                if (this.ageMin != 0 && this.ageMax != 0) {
                                    if (this.ageMin == this.ageMax) {
                                        ageCategoryText += this.ageMax + ' ' + years;
                                    } else {
                                        ageCategoryText += this.ageMin + ' - ' + this.ageMax + ' ' + years;
                                    }
                                } else if (this.ageMin == 0 && this.ageMax != 0) {
                                    ageCategoryText += ' < ' + this.ageMax + ' ' + years;
                                } else if (this.ageMin != 0 && this.ageMax == 0) {
                                    ageCategoryText += ' > ' + this.ageMin + ' ' + years;
                                } else {
                                    ageCategoryText = '';
                                }
                            } else {
                                ageCategoryText = this.getSelectText(this.ageCategories, this.ageCategorySelect);
                            }
                        }

                        if (this.gradeSelect == 3) {
                            gradeText = ' - ' + grade + ' : ';
                            if (this.gradeMin != 0 && this.gradeMax != 0) {
                                if (this.gradeMin == this.gradeMax) {
                                    gradeText += this.getSelectText(this.grades, this.gradeMin);
                                } else {
                                    gradeText += this.getSelectText(this.grades, this.gradeMin) + ' - ' + this.getSelectText(this.grades, this.gradeMax);
                                }

                            } else if (this.gradeMin == 0 && this.gradeMax != 0) {
                                gradeText += ' < ' + this.getSelectText(this.grades, this.gradeMax);
                            } else if (this.gradeMin != 0 && this.gradeMax == 0) {
                                gradeText += ' > ' + this.getSelectText(this.grades, this.gradeMin);
                            } else {
                                gradeText = '';
                            }
                        }

                        return teamText + ' ' + this.getSelectText(this.genders, this.genderSelect) + ' ' + ageCategoryText + ' ' + gradeText;
                    }
                },

                methods: {
                    addCategory: function addCategory() {
                        this.error = '';
                        // Get Get Category Name and Id

                        dualListIds = [];
                        $(".listbox-filter-disabled > option").each(function () {
                            dualListIds.push(this.value);
                        });

                        let categoryData = {
                            "isTeam": this.isTeam,
                            "gender": this.genderSelect,
                            "alias": this.alias,
                            "ageCategory": this.ageCategorySelect,
                            "ageMin": this.ageMin,
                            "ageMax": this.ageMax,
                            "gradeCategory": this.gradeSelect,
                            "gradeMin": this.gradeMin,
                            "gradeMax": this.gradeMax
                        };
                    },


                    decodeHtml: function decodeHtml(html) {
                        var txt = document.createElement("textarea");
                        txt.innerHTML = html;
                        return txt.value;
                    },
                    getSelectText: function getSelectText(myArray, val) {
                        var newVal = '';
                        myArray.map(function (el) {
                            if (val == el.value) {
                                newVal = el.text;
                            }
                        });
                        return newVal;
                    },
                    resetModalValues: function resetModalValues() {
                        this.isTeam = 0;
                        this.genderSelect = 'M';
                        this.ageCategorySelect = 0;
                        this.ageMin = 0;
                        this.ageMax = 0;
                        this.gradeSelect = 0;
                        this.gradeMin = 0;
                        this.gradeMax = 0;
                    }
                },
                filters: {
                    selectText: function selectText(val, myArray) {
                        return this.getSelectText(myArray, val);
                    },
                    html: function html(_html) {
                        return this.decodeHtml(_html);
                    }
                }
            });
```

And the HTML:

```
<select v-model="genderSelect" class="form-control">
            <option v-for="gender in genders" v-bind:value="gender.value">
                @{{ gender.text }}
            </option>
        </select>
```

Thing is before migrating to webpack, it was working :(

Any Idea what should be wrong?

Comment: With vuejs 2 it is not recommended to mount the instance on the body https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#el

Comment: I know, but when I tried to change it, I got a lot of weird errors. Should it work with body, or is it mandatory?

Comment: This was the error. I changed the template so that there were no <script> </script> inside, and it worked! Please put it as an answer